# R calculate mode for three columns by ID

Tags: r, mode

My dataframe has a few single data ("Weight", "Temperature"), and three scores for Hindlimb clasping ("Hindlimb_1", "Hindlimb_2", "Hindlimb_3"); all taken at different ages ("Age").

```
str(hindlimb_data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ ID            : Factor w/ 25 levels "26623","26625",..: 2 4 3 5 6 12 9 14 10 15
 $ Sex           : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
 $ Genotype      : Factor w/ 3 levels "NTg","Transgenic_1",..: 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 3
 $ Group         : Factor w/ 2 levels "Cross_sect","Longitudinal": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Age           : num  8 8 8 8 8.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5
 $ Weight        : num  30.8 31.2 28 27.5 32 33.2 26.7 32.5 27.2 29.2
 $ Temperature   : num  24.8 25.6 26.5 24.4 24.4 25.9 24.4 24.2 23.9 23.9
 $ Hindlimb_1    : num  2 2 3 0 2 2 0 2 2 0
 $ Hindlimb_2    : num  2 0 3 0 0 3 0 2 0 0
 $ Hindlimb_3    : num  2 0 3 0 0 2 0 2 0 1
```

I'm trying to calculate the mode of three Hindlimb clapsing data scores ("Hindlimb_x") for each subject ("ID"). I only seem to be able to calculate this when each score is entered longwise, in a separate row (but this would duplicate values for the other variables in my dataframe; e.g. weight, temperature).

Any ideas on how to code it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include the code of your attempts. What have you tried to do?

Comment: Hi, I coded the Mode function:

Comment: Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

Comment: Then ran this code to make a new variable for the Mode:

Comment: hindlimb_data$hindlimb_mode <- hindlimb_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Hindlimb_'), Mode), .groups = 'drop')

Comment: ...which replicates the columns for ID, Hindlimb_1, Hindlimb_2 and Hindlimb_3.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We group by 'ID' and loop `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'Hindlimb_' and return the `summarise`ed 'Mode'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with('Hindlimb_'), Mode), .groups = 'drop')
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Comment: This seems to output the variables "ID", "Hindlimb_1", "Hindlimb_2" & "Hindlimb_3", but I'm not getting the mode calculated

Comment: @asud I showed the `Mode` function int the post. Not clear what you meant